# SAS Connect SMP Error

Tags: sas

I had a code which was using SAS Connect (SMP) on my multiprocessor local machine to run similar but independent piece of code in parallel on different  processors of my local machine. This was running fine until yesterday but there seems to be an issue with it now as it throws the following error.

" **A communication subsystem partner link setup request failure has occured** "

I didn't change anything in my code..don't think it's the issue of licence expiring as I bought it recently...could you please help me out..

The code I am running is

```
options autosignon sascmd = "!sascmd"; 

%macro test(n); %do r =1 to &n.;
  signon task&r.; 
  rsubmit task&r. persist = yes wait = no sysrputsync = yes; 
    Remaining code.... 
  endrsubmit..
%end;
%mend test();

%test(100);
```

Comment: Please post the code you are running that generates this error message. Without further details it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. What do you get in the log if you run the following?  

 `signon test1 sascmd=!sascmdv;`

Comment: Hi there..The code is .....options autosignon sascmd = "!sascmd";                   %macro test(n);   %do r =1 to &n.;                  signon task&r.;   rsubmit task&r. persist = yes wait = no sysrputsync = yes;                                             Remaining code.... endrsubmit..%end;    %mend test();     %test(100);

Comment: I am sharing the log too

Comment: Do you get the same error message if you just run one `rsubmit` block without using your macro to generate the code?

Comment: Let me check quickly..btw how do i share my log with you..is there a way i can atach for u to see it ? Many thanks

Comment: Edit your question and post it below the code. Use the formatting button that looks like `{}` to post it in a blockquote like the code excerpt I added.

Comment: Helo, I am strruggling to put the log in my original post as it  is throwing a formatting error everytime

Comment: Please bear with me for some more time..Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it inot letting me do that...I am writing the final 4 lines where the error occurs...

Comment: ERROR : A communication subsystem partner link setup request failure has occured                                                                                                               ERROR : Netweok Request failed (rc 0x0AD0EAAC                                                                        ERROR: Remote Sigon to Task1 canceled

Comment: I can try putting a new query again, if u want to have a look at longer log..Many thanks

Comment: Guys..pls check my other post..i have put my log too now

Comment: Also, if I run rsubmit without using Macro and try this..

signon task1 sascmd = "!sascmd" ;

rsubmit task1 persist = yes wait = no sysrputsync = yes;
data test;
input a b;
datalines;
1 2 
3 4
;
run;
endrsubmit

Comment: It still shows the same error. The log is below :

9    signon task1 sascmd = "!sascmd" ;
NOTE: Remote signon to TASK1 commencing (SAS Release 9.03.01M0P060711).
ERROR: A communication subsystem partner link setup request failure has occurred.
ERROR: Network request failed (rc 0x0A2CEAAC) -
ERROR: Remote signon to TASK1 canceled.
10
11
12   rsubmit task1 persist = yes wait = no sysrputsync = yes;
ERROR: A link must be established by executing the SIGNON command before you can communicate with
       TASK1.
ERROR: Remote submit to TASK1 canceled.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going on inbetween your rsubmits but here is a variation if have tested at our sas site. I have added a waitfor *all* and signoff *all* to make sure the threads all run and finish before your main program ends. Also, make sure to 'restart' you sas service if its running in the background. 100 threads is a lot to do concurrently on 4 processors for example so I have lowered this to 5 from 100. Also, try closing sas and any sas process left on your machine. Reboot if required. The communication partner link is typically a tcp error or connection error to the sas process starting up. You might also check your firewalls, disable them temporarily to see if that helps.

```
options autosignon sascmd = "!sascmd"; 

%macro test(n);
  %do r=1 %to &n.;
      signon task&r.;
      rsubmit task&r. persist = yes wait = no sysrputsync = yes; 
        data test;
          a= 5;
          put a=;
        run;
      endrsubmit;
  %end;
  waitfor _all_;
  signoff _all_;
%mend;

%test (5);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply. It is working fine now..Looks like a loop of 100 was too much for it to work...Thanks once again.